# Upgrading from Rails 4 to Rails 6 and handling Nested Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I am helping a client upgrade his application from Rails 4 to Rails 6, and one of his model objects isn't saving properly and I'm having trouble figuring out why. I think the main trouble is figuring out how to set up the `params.permit` based on a somewhat unorthodox parameter structure. The main problem at this point is that the nested parameter `frequency` isn't attaching to the `service_agreement` even though the data appears to be coming through in the parameters correctly. I would think that redefining the strong parameters would provide a solution, but I'm not sure if that's true.

From the Model

```
# Model object
class ServiceAgreement < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :frequency, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :frequency, reject_if: :reject_frequency
end
```

From the Controller

```
def create
  @service_agreement = ServiceAgreement.new(service_agreement_params)
    
  authorize @service_agreement
    
  if params[:service_agreement][:start_date].present?
    @service_agreement.start_date = @service_agreement.set_proper_date(params[:service_agreement][:start_date])
  end
    
  if params[:first] && params[:second] && params[:third]
    @service_agreement.phone_number = params[:first] + params[:second] + params[:third]
  end
    
  if params[:service_agreement][:end_date].present?
    @service_agreement.end_date = @service_agreement.set_proper_date(params[:service_agreement][:end_date])
  end
    
  if params[:location_id] && params[:location_id] == "master"
    @service_agreement.master = true
  elsif params[:location_id]
    @location = Location.find(params[:location_id])
    @service_agreement.location_id = @location.id
  end
    
  if @service_agreement.save
    redirect_to pick_services_service_agreement_path(@service_agreement), notice: "Service Agreement Successfully Created"
  else
    @account = @service_agreement.account
    @chosen_invoice_frequency = @service_agreement.try(:invoice_frequency)
    @default_invoice_frequency = @account.try(:invoice_frequency)
    
    @service_agreement.build_frequency unless @service_agreement.frequency.present?
    
    respond_with(@service_agreement)
  end
end
```

Here are the paramters as they come through from the form:

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "service_agreement"=>{"active_status"=>"active", "service_type"=>"on_site_shredding", "job_type"=>"recurring", "sa_name"=>"", "contact_name"=>"", "location_id"=>"45729", "department"=>"", "frequency_attributes"=>{"day_count"=>"", "week_count"=>"1", "month_count"=>"", "day_on"=>"", "date_on"=>"", "week_on"=>"", "once"=>"false", "second_day_on"=>"", "second_date_on"=>"", "second_week_on"=>"", "on_demand"=>"false", "third_day_on"=>"", "fourth_day_on"=>"", "fifth_day_on"=>"", "sixth_day_on"=>""}, "start_date"=>"01/06/2021", "end_date"=>"06/23/2021", "estimated_service_time"=>"15", "notes"=>"", "standard_minimum"=>"0.0", "next_day_minimum"=>"0.0", "same_day_minimum"=>"0.0", "rush_minimum"=>"0.0", "invoice_frequency"=>"immediate", "po_number"=>"", "taxable"=>"0", "tax_rate_id"=>"33", "organization_id"=>"15", "account_id"=>"41447"}, "same_info"=>"1", "first"=>"727", "second"=>"714", "third"=>"7750", "commit"=>"Save"}
```

Originally, the strong parameters were defined as follows:

```
def service_agreement_params        
  params.require(:service_agreement).permit(:account_id, :location_id, :organization_id, :minimum_storage, :minimum_delivery, :standard_minimum, :rush_minimum, :next_day_minimum, :same_day_minimum, :payment_method, :service_type, :active, :contact_name, :estimated_service_time, :phone_number, :notes, :department, :po_number, :invoice_frequency, :active_status, :taxable, :tax_rate_id, :sa_name, :job_type, frequency_attributes: [:id, :day_count, :week_count, :month_count, :day_on, :second_day_on, :third_day_on, :fourth_day_on, :fifth_day_on, :sixth_day_on, :date_on, :second_date_on, :week_on, :second_week_on, :service_agreement_id, :once, :on_demand])
end
```

I have redefined the strong parameters to cut down on unpermitted errors as follows:

```
def service_agreement_params
  params.permit(:start_date, :end_date, {
                  service_agreement: [
                    :account_id,
                    :location_id,
                    :organization_id,
                    :minimum_storage,
                    :minimum_delivery,
                    :standard_minimum,
                    :rush_minimum,
                    :next_day_minimum,
                    :same_day_minimum,
                    :payment_method,
                    :service_type,
                    :active,
                    :contact_name,
                    :estimated_service_time,
                    :phone_number,
                    :notes,
                    :department,
                    :po_number,
                    :invoice_frequency,
                    :active_status,
                    :taxable,
                    :tax_rate_id,
                    :sa_name,
                    :job_type,
                    { frequency_attributes: [
                      :id,
                      :day_count,
                      :week_count,
                      :month_count,
                      :day_on,
                      :second_day_on,
                      :third_day_on,
                      :fourth_day_on,
                      :fifth_day_on,
                      :sixth_day_on,
                      :date_on,
                      :second_date_on,
                      :week_on,
                      :second_week_on,
                      :service_agreement_id,
                      :once,
                      :on_demand
                    ] }
                  ]
                })
end
```

*EDIT:* Adding Frequency model based on comment

```
class Frequency < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :service_agreement

  validate :first_day_if_second
  validate :first_date_if_second
  validate :first_day_before_second
  validate :second_week_after_first
  validate :day_on_if_week_on
  validate :second_date_on_after_first
  validate :week_on_and_date_on_has_month
  validate :date_between_1_to_30
  validate :second_date_between_1_to_30

  private

  def first_day_if_second
    if second_day_on.present? && !day_on.present?
      errors.add(:day_on, "You must add a first day if you have a second.")
    end
  end

  def first_day_before_second
    if second_day_on.present? && day_on.present? && day_on >= second_day_on && second_week_on == nil
      errors.add(:second_day_on, "Your second day must be later in the week than the first.")
    end
  end

  def second_week_after_first
    if second_week_on.present? && week_on.present? && second_week_on <= week_on
      errors.add(:second_week_on, "Your second week for service for your frequency must be after the first")
    end
  end

  def day_on_if_week_on
    if week_on.present? && !day_on.present?
      errors.add(:week_on, "You must select a day on if you select a week")
    end
  end

  def second_date_on_after_first
    if second_date_on.present? && date_on.present? && second_date_on <= date_on
      errors.add(:second_date_on, "Your second date must be after the first.")
    end
  end

  def first_date_if_second
    if second_date_on.present? && !date_on.present?
      errors.add(:second_date_on, "You must have a first date if you have a second")
    end
  end

  def week_on_and_date_on_has_month
    if (week_on.present? || date_on.present?) && month_count == nil
      errors.add(:month_count, "You must have a month if you have weeks or dates selected")
    end
  end

  def date_between_1_to_30
    if date_on.present? && !date_on.between?(1, 30)
      errors.add(:date_on, "Your date for your frequency must be between 1 and 30")
    end
  end

  def second_date_between_1_to_30
    if second_date_on.present? && !second_date_on.between?(1, 30)
      errors.add(:second_date_on, "Your second date for your frequency must be between 1 and 30")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: No, it's not. I have confirmed that.

Comment: There are no validation errors in the logs, but I'll post it just in case

Comment: You should not need :service_agreement_id as a permitted parameter for frequency.

Comment: What's in the `build_frequency` procedure?

Comment: It adds a frequency object to the service_agreement if one doesn't already exist